# Getting value out of context or leaving them in?

Tags: haskell

Assume code below. Is there a quicker way to get the contextual values out of `findSerial` rather than writing a function like `outOfContext`?
The underlying question is: does one usually stick within context and use Functors, Applicatives, Monoids and Monads to get the job done, or is it better to take it out of context and apply the usual non-contextual computation methods. In brief: don't want to learn Haskell all wrong, since it takes time enough as it does.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
type SerialNumber = (String, Int)
serialList :: Map.Map String SerialNumber
serialList = Map.fromList [("belt drive",("BD",0001))
                          ,("chain drive",("CD",0002))
                          ,("drive pulley",("DP",0003))
                          ,("drive sprocket",("DS",0004))
                          ]
findSerial :: Ord k => k -> Map.Map k a -> Maybe a
findSerial input = Map.lookup input
outOfContext (Just (a, b)) = (a, b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming I understand it correctly, I think your question essentially boils down to “Is it idiomatic in Haskell to write and use [partial functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions)?” (which your `outOfContext` function is, since it’s just a specialized form of the built-in partial function `fromJust`). The answer to that question is a resounding **no**. Partial functions are avoided whenever possible, and code that uses them can usually be refactored into code that doesn’t.

The reason partial functions are avoided is that they voluntarily compromise the effectiveness of the type system. In Haskell, when a function has type `X -> Y`, it is generally assumed that providing it an `X` will actually produce a `Y`, and that it will not do something else entirely (i.e. crash). If you have a function that *doesn’t* always succeed, reflecting that information in the type by writing `X -> Maybe Y` forces the caller to somehow handle the `Nothing` case, and it can either handle it directly or defer the failure further to *its* caller (by also producing a `Maybe`). This is great, since it means that programs that typecheck won’t crash at runtime. The program might still have logical errors, but knowing before even running the program that it won’t blow up is still pretty nice.

Partial functions throw this guarantee out the window. Any program that uses a partial function will crash at runtime if the function’s preconditions are accidentally violated, and since those preconditions are not reflected in the type system, the compiler cannot statically enforce them. A program might be logically correct at the time of its writing, but without enforcing that correctness with the type system, further modification, extension, or refactoring could easily introduce a bug by mistake.

For example, a programmer might write the expression

```
if isJust n then fromJust n else 0
```

which will certainly never crash at runtime, since `fromJust`’s precondition is always checked before it is called. However, the type system cannot enforce this, and a further refactoring might swap the branches of the `if`, or it might move the `fromJust n` to a different part of the program entirely and accidentally omit the `isJust` check. The program will still compile, but it may fail at runtime.

In contrast, if the programmer avoids partial functions, using explicit pattern-matching with `case` or total functions like `maybe` and `fromMaybe`, they can replace the tricky conditional above with something like

```
fromMaybe 0 n
```

which is not only clearer, but ensures any accidental misuse will simply fail to typecheck, and the potential bug will be detected much earlier.

For some concrete examples of how the type system can be a powerful ally if you stick exclusively to total functions, as well as some good food for thought about different ways to encode type safety for your domain into Haskell’s type system, I highly recommend reading Matt Parsons’s wonderful blog post, [Type Safety Back and Forth](http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/10/11/type_safety_back_and_forth.html), which explores these ideas in more depth. It additionally highlights how using `Maybe` as a catch-all representation of failure can be awkward, and it shows how the type system can be used to enforce preconditions to avoid needing to propagate `Maybe` throughout an entire system.